# Laravel AJAX,JS,Php 404error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.3

I have two connected `<select>` . The first one is static,the second one is depends of the first select value. 
I have a problem:`http://localhost/ajax-model?make_id=8 404 (Not Found)`
The page where is the two select.

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'','files'=>true))}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="make">Make</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="make" id="make">
        @foreach($make as $makes){
            <option value="{{$makes->id}}">{{$makes->title}}</option>
        }
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="model">Make</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="model">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
{{Form::close()}}
<script>

$('#make').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var make_id=e.target.value;
    //ajax

    $.get('/ajax-model',{make_id:make_id},function(data){
        //succes data
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    });
});

</script>
```

In a route:

```
Route::get('/ajax-model',function(){
    $make_id=Input::get('make_id');
    $model=CarModel::where('make_id','=',$make_id)-get();
    return Respone::json($model);
});
```

In a CarModel class:

```
class CarModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillabe=['make_id','title'];
}
```

I read a lot about that one,and everybody say,the `CSRF_token`,I added to the layout:

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

So,any idea?

Comment: Be careful when printing html, it should be:  `{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'','files'=>true)) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

first error is your passing url, you should change it like-

```
$.get('{{url('/')}}/ajax-model',{make_id:make_id},function(data){
    //succes data
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: ok , then please - `$model=CarModel::where('make_id','=',$make_id)-get();`  to `$model=CarModel::where('make_id','=',$make_id)->get();`, and let me know what is the new result

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: I solved. I needed to add: Response,Input alias,and to declare. Thank you for a help.